# Duplicate profile of front porch crown molding

Tags: trim

I want to rebuild external "crown" molding.  My main question is if you can copy the existing molding and then sanity check how I was thinking of building the replica.  Here is a low-mag view:
[image: low magnification view of crown molding]

, and a ruler to calibrate your eye:

[image: profile with ruler]

There are several layers of paint.  That combined with my inexperience has me puzzled.  Next is a partial cross-section:

[image: cross section]

I would prefer not to cut this up any more for another cross-section but I will if I need to.

Notice that there appears to be a cove at the very top of this cross section.  But I really can't get a good look.  Based on several other pictures as well as cutting some acrylic to size things, I came up with this:

[image: cad approximate view]

, but especially on the very top, it doesn't look correct.  Maybe this is a recognizable style for a profile.  I don't know the age, but the house was built in 1913 in Oregon, but I think the porch was added later.

I could also use some advice on how to replicate this.  I'm thinking I should use PVC trim that I machine.  I have access to a CNC or would buy a hand or table router if that would work best.

Thanks for any and all advice.

Comment: Strip the paint if you want to get the profile of the actual molding. Your top is wrong in part because it can be seen in the corner picture that the top of the top sticks out further than the lower part of the top, not the same as you have drawn.

Comment: I don't think you'll have a lot of luck with PVC trim...IME when cut the interior is rough.  Although I guess if you throw on enough layers of paint that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a market that is served by some millwork companies. If you use your favorite search engine to look for 'custom moulding' or 'custom milled trim', you can find more than a few companies which do custom profile runs just for restoration work. It will not be cheap, but it will get you a restoration grade match for the existing work.

Alternately, I've also seen this sort of work done with architectural foam that is cut using a custom router blade. Your proposal to machine trim also seems workable, though if you value your time I bet it comes in similar to custom moulding with a worse outcome. Your call if it's better to spend time or money on this.